# Can a laser bounce off molecules like water?

Tags: laser, molecules

Is it possible for a laser-beam to bounce off a molecule?

Comment: google for "molecular laser isotope separation"

Comment: Do you mean is it possible for a laser photon to be absorbed by a water molecule and then be re-emitted?

Answer (score 0):

A laser beam is composed of zillions of photons with fixed energy $hν$ where $ν$ is the frequency. A molecule is a quantum mechanical entity composed of electrons and nuclei in a bound state electromagnetically.

If the energy of the photons coincides with differences in energy levels of the molecule , it has a calculable probability ( quantum mechanics) to be absorbed, raising the energy level of some electron, or scatter elastically off the fringe electromagnetic fields of the molecule. In case its energy is larger then the energy of the bound electron levels, it can scatter in-elastically changing the level, and a new photon will take off with the remaining energy. There is always the probability of elastic scattering.

But a laser beam, cannot scatter off a single molecule. A photon from the beam can.